# How to add details from form to existing row in the access table?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

In MS Access, I have a table Student with a primary key studentId and another column Hours. I am creating a new form in access called enterHours.

When I add data in the form and the studentId is not present in the table, it should create a new entry in the table.

But when the studentId is already present in the table, it should add the number of hours to the existing number of hours in the table. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to have on the form 2 Textboxes: one bounded to the *Hours* field in the table, named *Hours*, and one unbounded, named *txtAddHours*. Make a button's Click event, or txtAddHours have an AfterUpdate event, add it's value to the value of the bounded Hours Textbox:

```
Private Sub txtAddHours_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Hours = Nz(Me.Hours, 0) + Nz(Me.txtAddHours, 0)
End Sub
```

IF the value in ***Hours*** filed does not have to be displayed, consider having Hours Textbox *Visible* attribute set to *False*.